# Android Printer Force close When clicking close button

Tags: android

```js
public class CropAgeDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = CropAgeDetailFragment.class.getName();
    private ImageView im;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private TextView tv;
    public static String nutritionRecommendation = "";

    private Map<Integer, Product> products = ShowCropsImages.cropMk.getCropAgeMks().get(AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk).getAgeMk().getProductsMap();
    private Button mBVutton;
    private Button printsms;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_age_detail_fragment, container, false);

        im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.im);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        printsms = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.sms);
        // mBVutton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.sms);
        ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.more)).setText("MORE");//AppProperties._morebutton);
        ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.video)).setText("VIDEO"+"");//AppProperties._videobutton);
        ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sms)).setText("PRINT"+"");//AppProperties._smsbutton);
        Log.i(TAG, "AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk ="+AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk);
        Log.i(TAG, "CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct ="+CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct);

//  Log.i(TAG, "videoPath="+HexaCropActivity.cropMK.getCropAgeMks().get(AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk).getAgeMk().getProductsMap().get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getVideos().toString());
//  HexaCropActivity.cropMK.getCropAgeMks().get(AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk).getAgeMk().getProductsMap().get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getVideos();

        view.findViewById(R.id.video).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    ShowCropsImages.cropMk.getCropAgeMks().get(AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk).getAgeMk()
                            .getProductsMap().get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getVideos().toString();
                    if(ShowCropsImages.cropMk.getCropAgeMks().get(AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk).getAgeMk()
                            .getProductsMap().get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getVideos().size() <= 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Videos are not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MkVideosGrid.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.more).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_SETTINGS, 0);

                final String language = settings.getString(AppConstants.LANGUAGE, "en");
                Log.i(TAG, "language = " + language);

                try {
                    if (language != "en") {
                        if(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleMorePdf().get(language)!=null){
                            Log.i(TAG,"products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleMorePdf().get(language) = "
                                    + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleMorePdf()
                                    .get(language));
                            Pdfloader(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleMorePdf().get(language));
                        }else{
                            Log.i(TAG, "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getMorePdf() = "
                                    + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getMorePdf());
                            Pdfloader(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getMorePdf());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getMorePdf() = "
                                + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getMorePdf());
                        Pdfloader(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getMorePdf());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "exception is ="+e.getMessage());
                    if (CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Information not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.sms).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                HomeActivity.data= "nutritionprint";
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Printer is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                im.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_SETTINGS, 0);

                final String language = settings.getString(AppConstants.LANGUAGE, "en");
                Log.i(TAG, "language = " + language);
                try {
                    if (language != "en") {
                        Log.i(TAG, "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleSms().get(language) = "
                                + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleSms().get(language));
                        tv.setText(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleSms().get(language));
                        nutritionRecommendation = products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleSms().get(language);
//      sendRequest(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocaleSms().get(language));

                    } else {

                        Log.i(TAG, "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getSms() = "
                                + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getSms());
                        tv.setText(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getSms());
                        nutritionRecommendation = products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getSms();
//      sendRequest(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getSms());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                HomeActivity.printerPojo.setDoctorName(settings.getString("username", ""));
                HomeActivity.printerPojo.setDoctorPhoneNumber(settings.getString("phone", ""));
                HomeActivity.printerPojo.setCropName(SelectCrop.cropName);
                HomeActivity.printerPojo.setCropAge("");
                HomeActivity.printerPojo.setPestName("");
                HomeActivity.printerPojo.setEtlValue("");
                HomeActivity.printerPojo.setRecommentdation(tv.getText().toString());
                Log.i(TAG,"SMS RECOMMENDATION : " + HomeActivity.printerPojo.getRecommentdation());
                Intent smsNutrition = new Intent(getActivity(), InitialActivity.class);
                startActivity(smsNutrition);
            }


        });


      

        view.findViewById(R.id.arrow).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SelectCrop.selectedNode == 1) {
                    IDTree.currentNodeBean.setNode(LiveObjs.live.getNode().getParent());
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectCrop.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                } else if (SelectCrop.selectedNode == 3) {
                    IDTree.currentNodeBean.setNode(LiveObjs.live.getNode().getParent());
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectCrop.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                }



            }
        });
        return view;

    }


    public void setImage(String string) {
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(string);
        im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnFail(R.drawable.dummy).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap process(Bitmap bitmap) {
               // im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 450, 400, false);
            }
        }).build();
        im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+string, im,options);

        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//  im.setImageBitmap(img);

        im.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Log.i(TAG,
                // "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf() =
                // "
                // +products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf());
                // Pdfloader(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf());

                SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_SETTINGS, 0);

                final String language = settings.getString(AppConstants.LANGUAGE, "en");
                Log.i(TAG, "language = " + language);
                try {
                    if (language != "en") {
                        if(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocalePdf().get(language)!=null){
                            Log.i(TAG, "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocalePdf().get(language) = "
                                    + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocalePdf().get(language));
                            Pdfloader(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getLocalePdf().get(language));
                        }else{
                            Log.i(TAG, "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf() = "
                                    + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf());
                            Pdfloader(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf() = "
                                + products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf());
                        Pdfloader(products.get(CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct).getPdf());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Some thing wrong with PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Pdfloader(String pdfpath) {

        File file = new File(pdfpath);
        Log.i(TAG, "file1 =" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.i(TAG, "is file =" + file.isFile());
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "if");
            if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),PdfFragment.class);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                try {
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There is no supported multiImagesListfile format available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "else");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PDF file is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



 

}
```

I Have show in bellow code is my activity is having printer when i click printer its to be printed after clicking close button its showing force close please giv me suggestion.. its happens only for first time printing

```
package com.tene.products.uasr.activities;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tene.platform.language.AppProperties;
import com.tene.platform.utils.AppConstants;
import com.tene.platform.utils.CommonUtils;
import com.tene.products.esap.service.params.ScreenMaster;
import com.tene.products.uasr.model.ScreenMasterManager;

import java.util.Map;

import tene.esap.state.LiveObjs;
import tene.split.util.mk.Product;

/**
 * Created by prashant on 27/3/17.
 */

public class CropAgeMkActivity extends Activity implements CropAgeListFragment.Communicator {
    // private boolean processClick = false;
    public static Button actionAudio;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private String audioFilePath;
   // final ScreenMaster scrnMaster = (new ScreenMasterManager(this)).getScreenMasterScreenId("SELECT_SYMPTOM");
    private long mLastClickTime = 0;
    private static final String TAG = AgeBio2MainActivity.class.getName();
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    int pos;
    private TextView mTitleage;
    private Button mPrintSms;
   // private Object mActivity;
    private Activity mActivity;

  // private Map<Integer, Product> products = ShowCropsImages.cropMk.getCropAgeMks().get(AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk).getAgeMk().getProductsMap();


    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.crop_age_activity_main);
         mTitleage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.head);
         mTitleage.setText(AppProperties._SSABI);

        findViewById(R.id.homebutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CropAgeMkActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Are you sure,want to go to home? ").setMessage("Survey will be cancelled.").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)                        //Do nothing on no
                        .show();
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

      /*  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_view, null);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
        actionBar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        actionBar.show();

        TextView title = (TextView) cView.findViewById(R.id.action_title);
        title.setText("Tene");
        cView.findViewById(R.id.homebutton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cView.findViewById(R.id.homebutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(CropAgeMkActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        // processClick = true;
        cView.findViewById(R.id.action_back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 2000) {
                    return;
                }
                mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                // if (processClick) {
                // processClick = false;
                onBackPressed();
            }
            // processClick=true;
            // }
        });

        actionAudio = (Button) cView.findViewById(R.id.action_audio);*/
       /* audioFilePath = CommonUtils.getAudioFilePath("IDTree.wav");
        if (scrnMaster.getScreenAudioExplainFile() != null) {
            audioFilePath = CommonUtils.getAudioFilePath(scrnMaster.getScreenAudioExplainFile().substring(0,
                    scrnMaster.getScreenAudioExplainFile().indexOf(".")) + "_" + LiveObjs.live.getSelectedLanguage()
                    + ".mp3");
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "audio file path  ==" + audioFilePath);

        if (!AppAudioPlayer.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAudioStatus()) {
            actionAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            AppAudioPlayer.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).startPlaying(audioFilePath);
        }

        actionAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppAudioPlayer.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).startPlaying(audioFilePath);
            }
        });*/

    }

    @Override
    public void Message(String string) {
        CropAgeDetailFragment detailfragment = (CropAgeDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.crop_age_detail_Fragment);
        if (detailfragment != null && detailfragment.isInLayout()) {
            detailfragment.setImage(string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
//      if (LiveObjs.live.getCurrentNode().getNode().getNodeType().equalsIgnoreCase("IDD")) {
//          LiveObjs.live.getCurrentNode().setNode(LiveObjs.live.getCurrentNode().getNode().getParent());
//          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectNode.class);
//          i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//          i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//          startActivity(i);
//      } else {
        CropAgeListFragment.selectedproduct = 0;
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AgeBio2MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
//      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        HomeActivity.currentActivity = 4;
        settings = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_SETTINGS, 0);
        String macId = settings.getString("printermacid", "NoPrinter");

        if (macId.equalsIgnoreCase("NoPrinter")) {
            findViewById(R.id.sms).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.sms).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }


}
```

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.tene.products.uasr.activities, PID: 20139
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tene.products.uasr.activities/com.tene.products.uasr.activities.CropAgeMkActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Map tene.split.util.mk.CropMk.getCropAgeMks()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Map tene.split.util.mk.CropMk.getCropAgeMks()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.tene.products.uasr.activities.CropAgeDetailFragment.<init>(CropAgeDetailFragment.java:60)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:622)
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:109)
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1801)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:944)
                                                                                       at com.tene.products.uasr.activities.CropAgeMkActivity.onCreate(CropAgeMkActivity.java:53)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Crash occuring because of the Null reference access in the CropAgeDetailFragment constructor . Please check the code

Comment: it means that is an fragment

Comment: Can you post the code for CropAgeDetailFragment too?

Comment: ya i will send CropAgeDetailFragment

Answer (score 1):

The app crashing on this line ,

```
private Map<Integer, Product> products = ShowCropsImages.cropMk.getCropAgeMks().get(AgeListFragment.selectedAgeMk).getAgeMk().getProductsMap();
```

From my understanding `ShowCropsImages.cropMk` is null.

Comment: You should initialize ShowCropsImages.cropMk before you use it.